# Type mismatch - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm running into a problem when trying to use the following code.  It runs perfectly in Firefox, Safari, Chrome, and IE 9+10, but causes the rest of my page to 'crash' when running in IE8.  The console error I receive is 'type mismatch' and the debugger points to the IF statement line.  I've been banging my head against the wall trying to figure it out, but to no avail.  Does anyone have a clue as to what the heck is going on here?

```
function writeIframe11092()
{
    alert("BEFORE");
    document.write('<iframe style=\"position:absolute;left:-40000px;\" src=\"https://mydomain.com/images/close.gif\" ></iframe>');
    alert("AFTER");
}

if (window.attachEvent) 
    window.attachEvent('onload', writeIframe11092() );
else if (window.addEventListener) 
    window.addEventListener('load',  writeIframe11092(),false);
```

Comment: Can you try with curly braces after if statement?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`writeIframe11092()` calls the function and returns a value (`undefined` in this case), and passes that value to `attachEvent`.

`writeIframe11092` is a variable representing the function itself, that's what you want to use here.

```
if (window.attachEvent){
    window.attachEvent('onload', writeIframe11092);
}
else if (window.addEventListener){
    window.addEventListener('load', writeIframe11092, false);
}
```

Comment: My favorite part about StackOverflow isn't receiving help to solve a problem (although that's very helpful) but gaining knowledge that I can apply to future problems.  The way you just answered this question blew my mind.  Greatly appreciate the answer!

Comment: @deniatus: You're welcome. I try. :)  When I answer, I like to explain why the method tried wasn't working, not just "here's the right answer" :)